# c/c++で文字列変換無しで小数点以下の桁数が求めたい

Tags: c++, c

c/c++で文字列への変換無しで小数点以下の桁数を求めたいです。  
e.g)
1.0 -> 0
1.1 -> 1
0.001 -> 3

```
float x= 0.4002;
int i=0;
while( x != floor(x) )
{
  x*=10;
  ++i;
}
```

一応こんな方法は思いついたのですが、
浮動小数だと正確に10倍されずに正しい桁数が出ないことが判明したので 正確に小数点以下の桁数を求める方法があれば教えてください。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 浮動小数だと正確に10倍されずに正しい桁数が出ない

そこまで理解されていればもう少しです。正確に10倍できないのと同じように `0.1` は正確には 0.9999999999... を適当なところで四捨五入して `0.1000000000` とみなして扱っているに過ぎません。
また有効精度は10進数で8桁程度であり、例えば1億辺りの値を扱うと１の位に誤差が現れ小数点以下の値は保持できなくなります。

以上を踏まえて、誤差をどこまで許容するかの問題でしかありません。

---

後は `x*=10;` のように演算を繰り返すと誤差が積算されていくため、`x * 100`、 `x * 1000`のようになるべく整数演算を行い、浮動小数点数の演算を1回で完了させることで誤差を抑えることができます。

Answer (score 4):

外部ライブラリ [Boost.Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) を利用可能であれば、基数10の任意精度浮動小数点数として計算することもできます。下記コードでは「基数10で100桁精度の浮動小数点数型」を利用しています。

```
#include <cassert>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;

// 基数10の100桁精度浮動小数点数型
using dec_float = mp::number<mp::cpp_dec_float<100>>;

int main()
{
  dec_float x{"0.0123456789012345678901234567890123456789"};
  int i = 0;
  while( x != floor(x) )
  {
    x *= 10;
    ++i;
  }
  assert(i == 40);
}
```